# Is it possible to utilize the same service worker for two projects?

Tags: service, service-worker, workbox

I have an issue with a service worker, I have two different projects that are in the same server but in different folders, and I want to precache the files on project number 2 using my service worker (My service worker is already working on project number 1). My question is, is it possible to do this? is there any other way I can attack this? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, as long as the service worker is hosted at a URL that is at the same level (or "higher") than the root of each of those projects. That would ensure that each project will be within scope of the service worker.

I'm assuming that one of the challenges you're asking about relates to creating a precache manifest within that service worker that contains build artifacts from both projects. There are a few different ways to tackle that, but I think the most straightforward would be to ensure that you always run the build process for each project at the same time, and then when you use Workbox's build tooling to create the precache manifest, you ensure that you grab all the assets that were output by each of the projects.

The specifics of configuring that build process depends on what you're currently using. You mention that there's a service worker (presumably using Workbox's precaching) already in place for the first project, so I think just using the same build setup, with tweaks to pick up the additional assets, would be easiest.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. I have actually read most of your articles on service workers, they have been really helpful so thank you very much. I will try your solution.

Comment: And also I will like to ask you, If I wanted to use workbox precaching would there be any problem doing this in the root folder? Because it asks you in which folder do you want to serve. It is mainly the precache part that I'm not very sure of.

Comment: You can run it from the root folder, sure. Just double-check the generated manifest to ensure that it includes all the assets you care about, and tweak your configuration if it doesn't.